# Something similar to selectize.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, selectize.js

Is there something similar to selectize.js for typescript (for angular specifically) with more documentation and some examples with the code,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [angular material chips](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)